# SQL query with 2 AND possible?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query in SQL

```
    $querycountry = mysql_query("SELECT 
  `country_iso2` 
FROM
  `ban_country_ip` 
WHERE `ip_from` <= INET_ATON('$ip') 
  AND ip_to >= INET_ATON('$ip') 
  AND checkbox = 1 
ORDER BY NAME ");
```

Is it a valid query if i added the second AND.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this.

Comment: Could you go more into detail?

Comment: Ya why not, did you tested?

Comment: Do you have any reason why you think it shouldn't be valid?

Comment: Well that is the problem don't know if my script is not working because of this or because of another thing so i need to clear out if it's ok to add 2 AND's in one query AND ip_to >= inet_aton('$ip') AND checkbox = 1 order by name, i don't know if mysql allows me.

Comment: This will only be true when all the three `AND` conditions returns true

Comment: You can also use `BETWEEN` for the ip conditions

Comment: Are you sure the 'from' and 'to' are in the right order? Are you sure the >= and <= shouldn't be round the other way?

Comment: If your SQL query would be invalid, an exception would be thrown with a SQL error message

Comment: might be logic is not right from <= and to >=, replace sign , menas from >= and to <=, and try

Comment: check this query in phpmyadmin whether it returns you results or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a valid query if i added the second AND.

Yes it is. You can use multiple conditions for a single query and `AND` or `OR` is used to add more than one conditions.

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

> You can specify more than one conditions using AND or OR operators.